# How to create nested dictionaries from excel sheet using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am new to programming and am trying to do the following (so far unsuccessfully):

I have an excel spreadsheet with `product codes`, `sellers` and `prices` and **am trying to update the `prices` in my spreadsheet** from two different spreadsheets sent by wholesalers.

I want a program to correctly

- search an excel spreadsheet and
- copy the corresponding `price` from there to the correct location above.

So I want to, for example:

- download the `price` for `product code` `'92526'` sold by wholesaler A.

I want to leave the manufacturer `price`s untouched.

> I had a program which was doing that correctly,
>   **except that I was telling it to iterate for every line in my spreadsheet and it was erasing the existing prices for manufacturers**.

I want a dictionary in the format:

```
{92526: {'price': 5.5, 'seller': 'Wholesaler A'}, 
 97056: {'price': 19, 'seller': 'Wholesaler A'}, 
 ...
}
```

---

I tried adding a screenshot of a spreadsheet with sample data but couldn't, so here it goes:

```
Product Code    Seller         Price
92526         Wholesaler A    5.5
97056         Wholesaler A    19
97055         Wholesaler B    15
97054         Wholesaler B    4.5
925AAT        Manufacturer    3.99
925AAF        Manufacturer    6.75
```

Columns are not representative of the actual columns in my spreadsheet.

The code I have is this (again, beginner):

```
import openpyxl
import pprint

data = {}
files = {'My_main_file':'my_file.xlsx',
         'File_WholesalerA':'FileA.xlsx',
         'File_WholesalerB':'FileB.xlsx'
         }

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['My_main_file'])                   
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['File_WholesalerA'])                
wb3 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['File_WholesalerB'])           
sheet1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Master Database')
sheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('sheetA')
sheet3 = wb3.get_sheet_by_name('sheetB')

# Collect all product codes in my database spreadsheet and add them as keys to the empty dictionary
for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet1['E' + str(row)].value
    data[code] = code

# Get Wholesaler A prices and add them to data dictionary
for row in range(2, sheet2.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet2['A' + str(row)].value
    if code in data:
        data[code]['price'] = sheet2['J' + str(row)].value
        data[code]['seller'] = 'Wholesaler A'

# Get Wholesaler B prices and add them to prices dictionary
for row in range(2, sheet3.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet3['A' + str(row)].value
    if code in data:
        data[code]['price'] = sheet3['K' + str(row)].value
        data[code]['seller'] = 'Wholesaler B'

# Paste the prices collected into the dictionary into my excel sheet for each #corresponding product code
for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet1['E' + str(row)].value
    if code in data:
        # Here I try to ensure that the code only updates the prices for the 
        # corresponding sellers and doesn't overwrite the prices for 
        # manufacturers.
        if sheet1['C' + str(row)].value == data[code]['seller']:
            sheet1['K' + str(row)].value = data[code]['price']

# Save another version of the spreadsheet with the data
wb1.save('My_main_file v2.xlsx')

pprint.pprint(data)
```

The expected result is for the program to scan the (10k +) lines of the Wholesaler spreadsheets, find the price corresponding to my product code and paste it into my sheet overwriting the old price but not erasing any other price.

My initial program managed to collect the prices and paste them to the corresponding product codes, but it erased the manufacturer prices which I had. This new program wont even populate the dictionary for some reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: aren't you getting an error? you should because of the combination of `data[code] = code` and then `data[code]['price']`. I think you need to change in the first loop to `data[code] = {}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tomerikoo. I am looking for a dictionary in the following form:

Comment: Let's say you start with an empty dictionary, `data = {}` and the first code is `92526`. After doing `data[code] = code` you will get the `data` dictionary to be: `{92526: 92526}`

Comment: Hi @Tomerikoo, I was not getting errors on that particular point for some reason. But your proposed solution worked very well. Thank you for the help !

Comment: And sorry for my unfinished edit of the comment. I submitted it by mistake. @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0):

This assignment can't be done

```
data[code]['price'] = sheet2['J' + str(row)].value
data[code]['seller'] = 'Wholesaler A'
```

You can try this structure if it helps you out

```
data[code] = {'price': sheet2['J' + str(row)].value,
              'seller': 'Wholesaler A'}
```

Edit:

The assignment I mentioned above can be done, but your dictionary needs to know it has nested dictionary inside it as Tomerikoo commented above me,
you could initial the line data[code] = {} and then it will work too.
Right now you'll jsut get an error saying:
 TypeError: 'str'/'int'/etc object does not support item assignment

Comment: @stovfl he wanted his dictionary in that format, up to now the code might have not worked because of this

Comment: Your solution, using `data[code] = {'price':...` will prevent the first `Traceback` but end up with: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Using `data[code] = {}` it will end up with: `KeyError: 'seller'`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. @Tomerikoo 's idea did produce the dictionary in the format that I wanted. But as stovfl indeed I incurred the keyError at the end.

I went for a more straight forward solution to this. In my main spreadsheet  I only had product codes for products sold by wholesalers, which means that when I iterated over every line, products sold by manufacturers were coming into the dictionary with a missing product code as key, and when I pasted that data back into my spreadsheet, it screwed everything up.

Comment: What I did instead was to create product codes for every line and bring in product codes as well as prices. Then my code just overrides the prices in the dictionary with the latest prices.

Comment: ```for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet1['E' + str(row)].value
    price = sheet1['K' + str(row)].value
    data[code] = price```

Comment: Also, I have posted a follow-on question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083260/trying-to-update-prices-with-inconsistent-data-in-excel-using-openpyxl