# Trying to update prices with inconsistent data in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to update prices in an excel sheet of mine. These prices should be found in excel spreadsheets sent by suppliers, however their excel sheet has inconsistent data. I generally import the price of a single item but some items only have a price for a case (consisting of x items per case). I have the item quantities and am trying to create a program that can correctly update my prices automatically.

```
Product Code    Case Price         Unit Price
92526               19                5.5
97056               250               19
97055               145               
97054               200               
925AAT              45.50    
925AAF              40                6.75
```

```
import openpyxl
import pprint

# Set up an empty dictionary which will take key, value pairs = product codes and prices respectively
data = {}

# Set up list of product codes with missing prices in Wholesaler A file.
missing_prices = {}

files = {'My_main_file':'my_file.xlsx',
         'File_WholesalerA':'FileA.xlsx'
         }

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['My_main_file'])                   
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(files['File_WholesalerA'])                          
sheet1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Master Database')
sheet2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('sheetA')

# Collect all product codes in my database spreadsheet and add them as keys to the empty dictionary
for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet1['E' + str(row)].value
    price = sheet1['K' + str(row)].value
    data[code] = price

# Get Wholesaler A prices and add them to prices dictionary, overriding the old price. If single price is missing, use
# case price for the time being.
for row in range(2, sheet2.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet2['A' + str(row)].value
    if code in data:
        single_price = sheet2['J' + str(row)].value
        if single_price == 0 or single_price == '':
            missing_prices[code] = 0  # Append code of missing price as key to missing price dict and assign value of 0
            case_price = sheet2['I' + str(row)].value
            data[code] = case_price
        else:
            data[code] = single_price

# Correct Wholesaler A prices due to using case prices because of missing single prices (I have the number of units per case in my excel file)
for code in missing_prices.keys():
    for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
        if sheet1['E' + str(row)].value == code:
            missing_prices[code] = sheet1['I' + str(row)].value

    data[code] = data[code] / missing_prices[code]

# Paste the prices collected into the dictionary into my excel sheet for each #corresponding product code
for row in range(2, sheet1.max_row + 1):
    code = sheet1['E' + str(row)].value
    if code in data:
        sheet1['K' + str(row)].value = data[code]

# Save another version of the spreadsheet with the data
wb1.save('My_main_file v2.xlsx')

pprint.pprint(missing_prices)
pprint.pprint(data)
```

When I print the missing_prices dictionary it comes back blank for some reason. I still couldn't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated. Also, if anyone can think of a more efficient way of doing this I would be curious to see how. I am new to programming and want to lear how to be more efficient with my code.

Comment: ***"I have the item quantities"***: You didn't use `quantities` in your code?

Comment: @stovfl sheet1['I' + str(row)].value is the quantity (number of units per case).

Comment: ***"`sheet1[I...` is the quantity"***: Then you can skip your first loop: `# Collect all...` and your second loop: `# Correct ` and  do it all in the `# Paste` loop. This requires to change your `data[code] = ` in the `# Get` loop according the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074664/7414759).

Answer (score 1):

If a cell is empty in the Excel file, the value given by `openpyxl` is `None`. So your test should look like:

```py
if single_price == 0 or single_price is None:
```

Comment: Thanks @frankie567. Thanks for your suggestion. Can't believe it was something so small. Initially, however, it didn't work. I couldn't get missing_prices to populate at all. But then I thought to check what exactly was inside the cell that seems to be blank and in fact there were some 5 spaces in the cell and that is why the program didn't run even after your suggestion. Once I deleted the spaces, the program ran.

But without your suggestion I would still be scratching my head. Thanks.

Any ideas how to solve the space issue within the cells?

Comment: Perhaps using a regex for the spaces?

Comment: I'm thinking ```if single_price == 0 or single_price is None or single_price == space_regex:```  , where ```space_regex = re.compile(r'\s+')```. But this also fails.

Comment: Actually you don't need a Regex: `if single_price is None or single_price == 0 or str(single_price).strip() == ''` `strip` removes every blank characters at the beginning and the end of a string. So `"   "` becomes `""`. The string conversion is here to make sure we deal with strings and not integers (and thus to be able to call `strip`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Using the strip method works beautifully. Thanks.